# Как узнать имя роутера к которому я подключен?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi

Смысл программы крайне прост: получить имя сети роутера (SSID) и пароль (WPA-PSK) (если это возможно. В противном случае бду запрашивать у пользователя) и сгенерировать это всё в qr-код. Но я не знаю как получить имя сети и пароль

Comment: Что значит «имя роутера»?

Comment: Если бы кто угодно мог получить пароль, то какой же смысл в этом пароле?

Comment: какая операционная система?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Comment: Операционка-винда, имя роутера-имя сети(извиняюсь за это), а о пароле я сказал, что это не обязательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Для Линукс

Чуток исправленная библиотека (на гитхабе есть ещё форки, основная не рабочая):

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/alex-eri/python-networkmanager.git@master
```

и сам код:

```
import dbus.mainloop.glib
dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
import NetworkManager

active_connections = NetworkManager.NetworkManager.ActiveConnections

wifi_connections = filter(lambda x: x.Type == '802-11-wireless', active_connections)

print('ssid', 'security', 'password')
for wifi in wifi_connections:
    settings = wifi.Connection.GetSettings()
    secret = wifi.Connection.GetSecrets('802-11-wireless-security')
    print(
        settings['802-11-wireless']['ssid'],
        settings['802-11-wireless-security']['key-mgmt'],
        secret.get('802-11-wireless-security')
    )
```

### Или через gi

Мне кажется так перспективней

```
import gi
gi.require_version("NM", "1.0")
from gi.repository import NM
nm=NM.Client.new()

active_connections = nm.get_active_connections()
wifi_connections = filter(lambda x: x.props.type == '802-11-wireless', active_connections)

print('ssid', 'security', 'password')
for wifi in wifi_connections:
    connection = wifi.props.connection
    print(
        connection.get_setting_wireless().get_ssid().get_data().decode(),
        connection.get_setting_wireless_security().props.key_mgmt,
        connection.get_secrets('802-11-wireless-security', None)['802-11-wireless-security']['psk']
    )
```

## Для Виндовс

Запускай программу netsh и смотри её вывод:

Получить список сетей

```
list_text = os.popen('NETSH WLAN SHOW PROFILE').read()
```

Получить пароль от сети

```
password_text = os.popen('NETSH WLAN SHOW PROFILE '+ name +' KEY=CLEAR').read()
```

Текст разберешь через сплит или регулярками.